# Session array updated then reverts back to original state, How to stop this?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, session, multidimensional-array

I am trying two simple buttons which will alter a cart's quantity by +1 or -1 depending on which button is clicked.

I set these up using 2 forms with a hidden value using post.

I then used an "if" and "ifelse" statement to determine which one (if any) was clicked.

I have compared to a very similar script doing something very similar (which works) and I can't see what I have done wrong.

**The buttons**

```
<?php
echo ' <form action="' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="1" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="pr" value="' .$key. '" />';
echo '<button style="min-width:25px;height:25px;background-color:white;"><b>+</b></button>
    </form>';

echo ' <form action="' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="2" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="pr" value="' .$key. '" />';
echo '<button style="min-width:25px;height:25px;background-color:red;"><b>-</b></button>';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

**And the script for dealing with the POST data;**

```
<?php
if($_POST["bn"]=="1")
{
    $_SESSION["cart"][$_POST["pr"]]["quantity"] += 1;
}
elseif($_POST["bn"]=="2") {
    if($_SESSION["cart"][$_POST["pr"]]["quantity"] == 1) { 
        unset($_SESSION["cart"][$_POST["pr"]]);
    }else{
        $_SESSION["cart"][$_POST["pr"]]["quantity"] -= 1;
    }
}
?>
```

Now the script works fine in the way that it will reload the page and will amend the quantity as per the button I clicked. Using both the normal output and print_r() I can see the session array HAS updated. However, if I now click another button on the page (the same one or different) the script will apply the update back to the original array data and not the one it **should have** just updated.
I.e. if I sit there clicking +1 all day I will still only ever end up with 2 (the original one plus button the added one)

Please can someone help me find where I'm going wrong? Many Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a `session_start()` at the top.

Comment: Where do you set `$key` looks like it will always be ? Whatever value you set it to above this code

Comment: @vivek_23, this is actually just a snippet, session_start() is at the beginning of the doc tho, thanks for checking :)
@RiggsFolly, This is embedded in a parent loop for each product item which starts `code $cart = $_SESSION["cart"];
foreach($cart as $key => $value)` This should give me $key as the array key I want to edit, I think that works fine because it always picks up the right product, just reverts when the page is reloaded

Comment: I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work with the code you have show. I believe it's due to something else, is there any other code related?

Comment: Just another thought. Why not use JavaScript to update the value on screen then use a "save cart" button to save it? I think that would be a better user experience since the page only reloads once and not x times.

Comment: @Simon instead of unset, can you assign it to `0` and change the if condition to `<= 1` ? Also, you need to find a better way to have keys in your array and not trust on $_POST values.

Comment: @vivek_23, appreciate the advice, any suggestions to look into as an alternative?

Comment: @Simon Sure.. can you give more context on what `pr` is ?